# subspace of $L^2$

Tags: measure-theory, lp-spaces

Let $(X,B(X),\mu)$ a measurable space, for a positive finite measure $\mu$, we consider $H=L^2(X,d\mu)$, Let $A$ a closed subspace of $H$, we know that $A$ is a hilbert space, can we say that it exist a positive measure $\mu'$ such that $A=L^2(X,d\mu')$ ? 
For example can we say that Hardy space $\mathbb{H}^2(\mathbb{T})$ is a $L^2$ space

Comment: What's $B(X)$? Is $X$ a topological space and $B(X)$ the $\sigma$-algebra of Borel sets?

Comment: yeah it's that we can assume that $X$ will be a domain of $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: Please, try to make the titles of your questions (more) informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.*
From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 2):

If $B$ is an orthonormal basis for the Hilbert space $A$ then $A$ is isomorphic to $L^2(\#)$, where $\#$ is counting measure on $B$. (Commonly known as $\ell^2(B)$.) So yes, every Hilbert space is an $L^2$ space.

Can we make it $L^2(\nu)$ where $\nu$ is some measure on $X$? Yes, but not in any interesting way - $X$ has a subset with the same cardinality as $B$. This is really irrelevant; the measure doesn't really have anything to do with $X$ or $\mu$.

Comment: This result is famous but as theoretical result, for the example of Hardy space what is it the measure ?

Comment: For that Hardy space we know that $e^{int}$, $n\ge0$ is a basis, so we get counting measure on $\Bbb N$.

Comment: if we take $f$ a element of $H$, so what will be the measure of $\langle f\rangle$ ?

Comment: By $\langle f\rangle$ you mean the span of $f$? That's a one-dimensional Hilbert space. There's no such thing as the measure of a Hilbert space. It should be clear how to define a measure $\mu$ such that $L^2(\mu)$ has dimension $1$...

Comment: can you please explicit the construction of such measure on $X$ ?